# How to deactivate specific hot corner in gnome shell?

Tags: gnome-shell

I've installed "Custom Hot Corners - Extended" ([link](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4167/custom-hot-corners-extended/)). Ok it's great. Now I would like to "deactivate" (erase, remove) specific one. How can I do that? I have this right now, but it's still working:
[image]

When going with cursor to up-right corner it fails because I didn't specify the command but I would like to complitely deactivate that corner and have "-" again like here:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first item in the Actions menu is Disable. I don't understand why you didn't ask the extension author directly on the GitHub, you would get an answer almost immediately. I know it, I'm the author ;)

Comment: Thank you! I just didn't know there is such a place. :)